# Автоматическое пополнением баланса

Tags: php

Стоит вот такой код :

```
<form id=pay name=pay method="POST" action="https://merchant.webmoney.ru/lmi/payment.asp">
Деньги перечисляются посредством системы Webmoney<br><br>
Сумма зачисления: <input type="Text" name="LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT" value = "10" class="window" size="7"> WMR<br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_DESC" value="пополнение баланса от <?php print("$id_user $logus"); ?> ">
    <input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_NO" value="<?php print (date("dmGis")); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYEE_PURSE" value="R33333333333">
    <input type="hidden" name="LMI_SIM_MODE" value="0">
    <input type="Hidden" name="user" value="<?php print("$id_user"); ?>">
    <input type="Hidden" name="operation" value="open">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value = "Перечислить" class="field2" size="10">
</form>
```

Нужно, чтоб не только оплачивало, но еще и пополняло баланс, то есть чтоб после успешной оплаты через мерчант у пользователя пополнился баланс. Как реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

С этим кодом такого сделать нельзя.
Однако реализовать это возможно с помощью интерфейса Click&Buy Merchant Interface, читайте официальную вики: [Click&Buy Merchant Interface](http://wiki.webmoney.ru/wiki/show/Click%26Buy+Merchant+Interface)

Comment: Спасибо за инфу !
Вроде с этим разобрался!

Comment: Посмотри еще робокассу она поприкольней будет, там возможности шире, правда есть комиссии.